# How to compare huge number of strings in 2 or 3 minutes

Tags: c#, vb.net

I have two class or arrays. Class A has str1, str2, str3, str4, str5, str6. There are 200,000 A. Class B has St1, St2, St3, St4, St5, St6. There are 50,000 class B. If str1=St1 and str2=St2, then add the string to Product which has str1, str2, str3, str4, str5, str6, St3, St4, St5, St6.

The simplest way is to have two loops, but it really takes a very long time, I used to complete it in 6-8 hours. Later I tried to do the same thing in excel. I can complete in ~5 minutes. But sometimes it has error if someone is using excel . So I want to know whether I can still do that in code behind without using excel.

```
 Dim Products As ObservableCollection(Of Product)
    Dim lstProducts As New List(Of Product)

    for i=0 to ClassA.count-1
    for j=0 to ClassB.count-1
    if ClassA.item(i).str1 = ClassB.item(j).St1 and ClassA.item(i).str2 = ClassB.item(j).St2
    then 
    Dim p As New Product(str1, str2, str3, str4, str5, str6, St3, St4, St5, St6)
else
     Dim p As New Product(str1, str2, str3, str4, str5, str6, "", "", "", "")
    lstProducts.Add(p)
    end if
    next j
    next i

    Products = New ObservableCollection(Of Product)(lstProducts)
```

Comment: It's not going to save you much, but you should be using `AndAlso` instead of `And`. Here's a case where a *short-circuiting* logical operator will make a difference. The final solution will likely depend on the nature of your collections. You don't mention the types of your `strN` and `StN` properties. I'm guessing strings, but... Is the combination `(str1,str2)` unique in your `ClassA` collection?  What about `(St1,St2)` in `ClassB`? If a Dictionary works for you, that will reduce the problem from O(N2) to O(N). Presorting things might help, but perhaps not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `ClassB`, create a `Dictionary`, where key is a pair: `(St1, St2)`, and the values are lists of items from `ClassB`. For each `(St1, St2)`, it stores all items from `ClassB` which have these `St1` and `St2`. Now you should just iterate over `ClassA`, and, using dictionary, you can quickly find relevant items from `ClassB`.

The running time depends linearly on the size of the input and output.

Sorry, I don't know VB, so I can't write the code.

Comment: Hi Dmitry, it is really fast! I use the pair as suggested. It complete in less than 10 seconds. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You could do a couple of things. You could call GetHashCode on all those strings (do it only once per strong and store it somewhere). Then compare these internets instead of the strings.

A second thing you could do is create a Dictionary that stores all of string 1 as the key. Then loop through ClassB finding where dict.ContainKey(b.str1), and then compare the second string.

Comment: Hi crwells, I use dictionary. It is really fast! It complete in less than 10 seconds. Thank you very much.